# PostgreSQL - Select splitted rows based on a column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Could someone please suggest a query which splits items by working minutes per hour?

Source table

| start_timestamp | item_id | total_working_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 14:10 | A | 120 |
| 2021-02-01 14:30 | B | 20 |
| 2021-02-01 16:30 | A | 10 |

Expected result

| timestamp_by_hour | item_id | working_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 14:00 | A | 50 |
| 2021-02-01 14:00 | B | 20 |
| 2021-02-01 15:00 | A | 60 |
| 2021-02-01 16:00 | A | 20 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? The solution will most probably be quite different

Comment: Postgres will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a recursive query, which should work in both Redshift and PostgreSQL. First, extract

- The hour and amount of minutes worked the first hour
- The total minutes worked

Then, repeat by recursion for each row where the minutes worked in the current hour is less than total minutes worked. In the recursion, increase the starting hour by 1, and reduce total minutes worked by the minutes worked in the preceding hour.

Finally, aggregate the results by hour and ID.

```
with recursive 
  split_times(timestamp_by_hour, item_id, working_minutes, total_working_minutes) as
(
  select
    date_trunc('hour', start_timestamp),
    item_id,
    least(total_working_minutes, 60 - extract(minutes from start_timestamp)),
    total_working_minutes
  from work_time
union all
  select
    timestamp_by_hour + interval '1 hour',
    item_id,
    least(total_working_minutes - working_minutes, 60),
    total_working_minutes - working_minutes
  from split_times
  where total_working_minutes > working_minutes
)
select timestamp_by_hour, item_id, sum(working_minutes) working_minutes
from split_times
group by timestamp_by_hour, item_id
order by timestamp_by_hour, item_id;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2CQPGxuYRf7xG8d8S8EL95/0)

Comment: The query looks impressive, thanks!

Comment: @OleksiiLogvin Happy to help! After posting, I realised the toggle was unnecessary, and simplified the query a bit. It should be more readable now.

Comment: It is. Now it is impressively concise!